# Scrapy: how to check if a previously scraped page has been deleted?

Tags: python, database, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I made a simple Scrapy crawler that fetches ads for house prices in my city.

It collects the following data: AD TITLE, PRICE and URL. Then outputs a CSV file.

Each week I run the crawler, and I would like it to compare the newest CSV file with the previous one, to check if any ads have been removed. And if they have, I'd like it to include today's date in a LAST SEEN column of the CSV file output.

I have no idea if this can be done with CSV files, or if a database will be needed for this job. I also don't know if I need to create an item pipeline.

Here is my spider code for the moment.

```
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/'
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css('li.item a.list-link::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(item, callback=self.parse_item)

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@title="Next page"]/@href').extract_first()

        if next_page is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1.ad-title::text').extract_first()
        price = response.css('span.price::text').extract_first()

        yield {
            'TITLE': title,
            'PRICE': price,
            'URL': response.url
        }
```

Comment: you'll need a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with csv (or with any other datastructure really).

Lets immagine you crawled twice and now you have to files:

```
$ cat items1.csv 
some_url, foo1, bar1
some_url2, foo2, bar2
some_url3, foo3, bar3

$ cat items2.csv 
some_url, foo1, bar1
some_url3, foo3, bar3
```

What we can do is load all urls from those files, convert the values into python `set`s and call `set.difference` on your two sets to see how different are your datasets.

```
import csv
def read_file(filename)
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        urls = [row[0] for row in csvreader]
        return set(urls)

urls1 = read_file('items1.csv') 
# returns {'some_url', 'some_url2', 'some_url3'}
urls2 = read_file('items2.csv') 
# returns {'some_url', 'some_url3'}

# find the difference
deleted_urls = urls1.difference(urls2)
#returns: {'some_url2'}
```